# MySQL Error code 1067 default value Nro_alu

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas soy nuevo en mysql, estoy intentando crear una tabla segun el siguiente enunciado:
Crea una tabla ALUMNOS con las columnas: número de alumno (entero de tres
cifras, sin signo, rellenado con ceros y autoincrementado), nombre, apellidos,
dirección, dni. Establece restricciones: número de alumno es clave principal;
nombre, apellidos, dni son no nulos, y dni no admite valores repetidos.

De momento tengo esto:

pero al momento de ejecutar la tabla, me da el error Invalid default value for 'Nro_ALU'

```
CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS(
NRO_ALU TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT 000,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
APELLIDOS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DIRECCION VARCHAR(50) ,
DNI VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (NRO_ALU)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: El entero no te va a recibir valores rellenados. Puedes definir que el campo sea entero de longitud 3 y formatear lo que muestras al usuario para añadir los ceros que falten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El requerimiento quedaría satisfecho de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS
(
    NRO_ALU TINYINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(50) ,
    DNI VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NRO_ALU)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

- entero de tres cifras: `TINYINT`
- sin signo: `UNSIGNED`
- rellenado con ceros: `ZEROFILL`
- y autoincrementado: `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Establece restricciones:

- número de alumno es clave principal: `PRIMARY KEY (NRO_ALU)`.
- nombre, apellidos, dni son no nulos: `... NOT NULL` en cada uno de ellos
- dni no admite valores repetidos: `UNIQUE`

Tu `DEFAULT 000` no tiene ningún sentido en una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT`, basta con `TINYINT` para este caso, o si quieres con un `INT(3)`.

### Código de prueba:

```
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (NOMBRE,APELLIDOS,DIRECCION,DNI)
VALUES ('a1','b1','c1','d1'),('e1','f1','g1','h1');

SELECT * FROM ALUMNOS;
```

**Salida:**

Pongo captura de pantalla porque en los fiddle no se ven los zerofill:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]